# jQuery pause pre-display on hover for mega menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, megamenu

Got a lil one, need a mega menu to appear after a brief pause on hover else it shows up immediately with every mouse over which is a bit hectic.

Mega menu worked lovely until the hover thing became incredibly annoying!

Tried using `hoverIntent` but can't figure out the functions required for it to stop 'un-displaying' on mouse out of just the link, rather than the link and the menu if that makes sense?

My probably pants code is thus...

```
$("li.view_products a").add('.megamenu').hover(
    function(){
        $('.megamenu').removeClass('no_show');
    },
    function(){
        $('.megamenu').addClass('no_show');
    }
)
```

I have been scoping through previously asked questions and seen some mentions of `SetTimeOut` etc? but I can't make head or tail of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with a jquery accordion?

Comment: do you mean a plugin? i haven't tried that no, I always thought that was more for content sections rather than big menu dropdowns?